# Listing Components (not controls)

Tags: c#, winforms

My code displayed below shows all the visual and non-visual components of a form (OpenDialogs, SaveDialogs, etc). I wish I could specify the component name (no control) rather than knowing all the form elements, something like this:

```
private IEnumerable <Component> EnumerateComponents ()
{
    return this.GetType () GetFields (BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where (F => typeof (Component) .IsAssignableFrom (f.FieldType))
    .Where (F => typeof (Control) .IsAssignableFrom (f.FieldType))
    //.Where  componentName.thatIinformed == "OpenDialog1" <<<<<======
    .Select (F => f.GetValue (this))
    .OfType <Component> ();
}
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Because `Control` inherits from `Component` you don't need that second where clause - in fact it is restricting the results to only `Control` types and types derived from `Control` instead of at the `Component` level. Also, its not completely clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Anthony, thank you for your response. When I tell the component name, I will be able to catch only the properties of this component in another routine (PropertyInfo [] = component.GetProperties PropertyInfo ());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something more along the lines of this:

```
public IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
{
    return this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(x => typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType))
        .Select(x => x.GetValue(this)).Cast<Component>();
}
```

I tried this with the following custom `UserControl`:

```
public sealed class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
    // Adding some Controls for testing
    public Label MyLabel1 { get; set; }
    public Label MyLabel2 { get; set; }

    // Adding a Component (not a Control) for testing
    public System.Windows.Forms.Timer MyTimer1 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(x => typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType))
            .Select(x => x.GetValue(this)).Cast<Component>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> EnumerateProperties()
    {

        return this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(x => typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType));
    }
}
```

The `EnumerateProperties` method was just so I could test that it was picking up the properties I wanted. It included the 2 `Label` properties I added as well as the `Timer` property I included (because it isn't a `Control`, just a `Component`). It also picked up 6 other properties which it inherits from the `UserControl` which meet the criteria: `ActiveControl`, `ParentForm`, `ContextMenu`, `ContextMenuStrip`, `Parent`, and `TopLevelControl`.

Now, getting the values for each one of these is likely to return a lot of `null` values, so you may also need to filter out non-null values. Using `OfType` instead of `Cast` also has the side effect of removing null values.

Comment: Anthony, Thanks again. It is possible to include a parameter to perform a search for the component name?

Comment: A [`Component`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) doesn't have a `Name` property, only [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx)s do. Did you want to check the name of the `Control` if it is a `Control` or did you want to filter based on the type name?

Comment: Your explanations helped a lot. Thank you again Anthony.